# What's the http request for the page source?

Tags: c++, http, winsock

I've managed to make a file downloader in C++ (using winsock). It downloads every simple link with a file like: *www.page.com/image.png*

I want to make it download all of the images from an entire page, such as all the images from a 4chan thread, but I don't know what I should send in the http request to get the page's source. How can I request the source of a webpage?

Comment: Everything on the web is "simple links". The page you're viewing now? Just copy and paste the URL into your program and download it and you have the full source for the page.

Comment: Also, there are many programs that already does everything you seem to want, i.e. go to an URL, get the page, recursively download all images, etc. Start by looking for such programs instead of writing your own, especially since parsing HTML is not easy.

Answer (score 1):

You don't send anything in the `http` request, in the manner you're thinking.

An `http` request sends a single request, for a single document, and returns a single document from the server.

To download an entire page, you will have to parse the downloaded HTML document, extract all the relative links from the HTML source, then issue a separate `http` request for every image, css, js, etc... referenced from the main document.

This is how tools like [wget's --recursive option](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/#Recursive-Retrieval-Options) download entire pages.

Answer (score 0):

If the page is located at the root of the `http://www.page.com` server, you would send a `GET` request to the `www.page.com` server asking for the `/` resource:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.page.com
```

Let's say the page was actually located at `http://www.page.com/thepage.html`. You would send a `GET` request asking for `/thepage.html` instead:

```
GET /thepage.html HTTP/1.1
Host: www.page.com
```

Either way, you would then have to parse the resulting HTML to get the individual URLs of all the `<img>` tags that are on the page.